# How is this error possible? "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available" on internal MSXML2.DOMDocument30

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm running a Windows server 2019 VB.Net Web Service.  It runs fine except periodically I get the following error on a line that has been executed many, many times before the error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000000A): The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000A)
at MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList.get_item(Int32 index)
at LMWAPI.Service1.CMI_Setup(Object& oRoot, String[] CMI, String CMIDataElement, String strValue) in D:\Data\CADE.Net\LMWAPI\Service1.asmx.vb:line 548

```
Public mDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument30
...
Dim xList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim CMIroot() As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
...
547 xList = mDoc.getElementsByTagName(CMI(i))
548 CMIroot(i) = xList.item(0)
```

mDoc is a public variable and loaded at the start of the program and used many times before the error occurs.  It is never modified, only read throughout the program.  xList is defined locally in the subroutine with CMIroot.  Line 548 gets executed multiple times on each transaction and there are thousands of transactions in a day.   The error may only pop up once or twice a day.

So, is my problem that xList is not fully "ready" to use?.. is there a way to tell?  Or am I just completely off?

Comment: Have you considered using System.Xml instead of going through COM? It might be much faster and more reliable.

Comment: Actually, this is the only VB program I've written and it was like 10 years ago.  I can't say I know the difference.

Comment: Just looked it up... looks like a much better choice.

Comment: You might want to investigate [LINQ-to-XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview) to extract data. Of course, you can use XPATH queries if you're already using those.

Comment: Using a different library is not going to fix the issue if the root cause is the data inside the xml file.  Check the xList to see if it contains any data.  I suspect you are not getting any results.  The xml file is text so comparing a good xml file against a bad xml using a tool like Beyond Compare will help.

Comment: jsweng... XML doc is perfect.  Been checked many times, many sources, hasn't changed for over 10 years.  It contains the "rules" for processing SCORM.   Root cause is definitely not the XML contents.

Comment: Using System.XML had definitely made a difference!  Early yet but looking good Andrew!!

Comment: Andrew Morton: If you want to use your comment as the answer, I'll select it.  I haven't had the error since replacing the DomDocument30 with XMLDocument